# How to store data into variable with DateRangePicker from rsuite?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, daterangepicker, rsuite

I am trying to store a date range into an array using DateRangePicker from rsuite. Right now my application works as intended, but I am still getting some errors in Typescript. How do I do this correctly?

```
import { DateRangePicker } from "rsuite";

const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([]);

<DateRangePicker
   format="MM/dd/yyyy"
   character=" – "
   value={dateRange}          //value has error
   onChange={setDateRange}    //onChange has error
/>
```

> Value error: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '[Date, Date]'.
> Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)

> onChange error: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<never[]>>' is not assignable to type '(value: DateRange | null, event: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'DateRange | null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.ts(2322)

I have also tried the following but the "range" in setDate(range)" is also throwing an error

```
<DateRangePicker
   format="MM/dd/yyyy"
   character=" – "
   onChange={(range) => setDateRange(range)}    //2nd range has error
/>
```

> range error: Argument of type 'DateRange | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.ts(2345)

Comment: have you tried any of the suggested solutions? If yes please give the feedbacks :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like you're facing TypeScript type issues when using the DateRangePicker from rsuite. To resolve these errors, you need to provide appropriate types for the state and the onChange handler. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { DateRangePicker } from "rsuite";
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, SyntheticEvent } from "react";

interface MyComponentProps {
  // Add any other props if needed
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = () => {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState<[Date?, Date?]>([]);

  const handleDateChange = (
    value: DateRange | null,
    event: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>
  ) => {
    if (value) {
      setDateRange([value[0], value[1]]);
    } else {
      // Handle null case if needed
      setDateRange([]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
      character=" – "
      value={dateRange}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
    />
  );
};
```

1.The useState hook initializes dateRange as a tuple of optional Date types.

2.The handleDateChange function ensures that the value passed to setDateRange is a tuple of two optional Date types or an empty array.

This should resolve the TypeScript errors you're encountering. Adjust the types and handling according to your specific requirements.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  type which is defined as ``
The type of the `value` is `ValueType`.
Check the prop types in the [official doc](https://rsuitejs.com/components/date-range-picker/#props).
Just import the `ValueType` or use the type as `[Date?, Date?]`

You can check [sandbox running example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/datagrid-forked-version2-wfd7m8)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DateRangePicker } from "rsuite";
import { ValueType } from "rsuite/DateRangePicker";

export default function App() {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = React.useState<ValueType>([]);
  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
      character=" – "
      value={dateRange} //value has error
      onChange={setDateRange} //onChange has error
    />
  );
}
```